# How do you upgrade Textmate to version 2

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I have Textmate (1.5 I think) and thought I would look at the new version 2.
I cant find instructions anywhere on how to upgrade/get the new version!

I'm sure it must be really obvious but I just cant see how. Unless I have to compile from the source on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the textmate GitHub page, in the 'building' section, there is a link to download pre-built binaries:

GitHub page: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/downloads

Link to prebuilt binaries: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/downloads

Download and unpack whatever version you want and you should be able to launch the '.app' file.